# Hi, please I am trying to use plotly and dash to create a dashboard but my Select Stat will only show Regression Stat and my graphs aren't displaying

Tags: python, plotly-dash

The code:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# Load the data using pandas
data = pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DV0101EN-SkillsNetwork/Data%20Files/historical_automobile_sales.csv')

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Set the title of the dashboard
#app.title = "Automobile Statistics Dashboard"

# List of years 
year_list = [i for i in range(1980, 2024, 1)]

# Create the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    #TASK 2.1 Add title to the dashboard
    html.H1("Automobile Sales Statistics Dashboard",
    style={'textAlign':'center','color':'#503D36',
    'font-size':24}),
    html.Div([#TASK 2.2: Add two dropdown menus
        html.Label("Select Statistics:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown-statistics',
            options=[
                {'label':'Yearly Statitics','value':'Yearly Statistics Report',
            'label':'Recession Statistics', 'value':'Recession Period Statistics'}
            ],
            value='Yearly Statistics Report',
            placeholder='Select a report type'
        )
    ]),
    html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(
            id='select-year',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
            value=2000
        )),
    html.Div([#TASK 2.3: Add a division for output display
    html.Div(id='output-container', className='chart-grid', style={'display':'flex'}),])
])
#TASK 2.4: Creating Callbacks
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='select-year', component_property='style'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics',component_property='value'))

def update_input_container(dropdown_statistics):
    if dropdown_statistics =='Yearly Statistics Report': 
        return {'display':'block'}
    else: 
        return {'display':'none'}

#Callback for plotting
# Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output-container', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='select-year', component_property='value'), Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value')])


def update_output_container(select_year,dropdown_statistics):
    if dropdown_statistics == 'Recession Period Statistics' and select_year:
        # Filter the data for recession periods
        recession_data = data[data['Recession'] == 1]
        
#TASK 2.5: Create and display graphs for Recession Report Statistics

#Plot 1 Automobile sales fluctuate over Recession Period (year wise)
        # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
        yearly_rec=recession_data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        R_chart1 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(yearly_rec,
        x='Year',
        y='Automobile_Sales',
        title='Average Automobile Sales fluctuation over Recession Period'))

#Plot 2 Calculate the average number of vehicles sold by vehicle type       
        
        average_sales = recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()                           
        R_chart2 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(average_sales,
        x='Vehicle_Type',
        y='Automobile_Sales',
        title='Average Automobile Sales for each Vehicle Type in the Recession Period'))
        
# Plot 3 Pie chart for total expenditure share by vehicle type during recessions
        
        exp_rec= recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
        R_chart3 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.pie(exp_rec, 
        values ='Advertising_Expenditure',
        names='Vehicle_Type',
        title='Total Expenditure for each Vehicle Type during the Recession'))

# Plot 4 bar chart for the effect of unemployment rate on vehicle type and sales
        unemp_rec= recession_data.groupby(['Unemployment_Rate','Vehicle_Type'], as_index = False)['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        R_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(unemp_rec, 
        x='Unemployment_Rate', 
        y='Automobile_Sales', 
        hue='Vehicle_Type',
        title='Total Expenditure for each Vehicle Type during the Recession'))


        return [
            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart1),html.Div(children=R_chart2)],style={'display':'flex'}),
            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart3),html.Div(children=R_chart4)],style={'display':'flex'})
            ]

# TASK 2.6: Create and display graphs for Yearly Report Statistics
 # Yearly Statistic Report Plots                             
    elif dropdown_statistics == 'Yearly Statistics Report' and select_year: 
        yearly_data = data[data['Year'] == int(select_year)]
                              
#TASK 2.5: Creating Graphs Yearly data
                              
#plot 1 Yearly Automobile sales using line chart for the whole period.
        yas= data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        Y_chart1 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(yas, 
        x='Year',
        y='Automobile_Sales',
        title='Yearly Automobile Sales'))
            
# Plot 2 Total Monthly Automobile sales using line chart.
        mon= data.groupby('Month')['Automobile_Sales'].sum().reset_index()
        Y_chart2 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(mon, 
        x='Month',
        y='Automobile_Sales',
        title='Monthly Automobile Sales'))

            # Plot bar chart for average number of vehicles sold during the given year
        avr_vdata=yearly_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
        Y_chart3 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(avr_vdata,
        x='Vehicle_Type', 
        y='Automobile_Sales',
        title='Average Vehicles Sold by Vehicle Type in the year {}'.format(select_year))

            # Total Advertisement Expenditure for each vehicle using pie chart
        exp_data=yearly_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
        Y_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.pie(values='Advertising_Expenditure', 
        names='Vehicle_Type',
        title='Total Advertisement Expenditure for each Vehicle Type'))

#TASK 2.6: Returning the graphs for displaying Yearly data
        return [
                html.Div(className='chart-item', children=      [html.Div(children=Y_chart1),html.Div(children=Y_chart2)],style={'display':'flex'}),
                html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart3),html.Div(children=Y_chart4)],style={'display':'flex'})
                ]
        
    else:
        return None

# Run the Dash app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I expected this code to display a Dropdown with two options-'Yearly Statistics Report' and 'Recession Period Statistics' and a Dropdown to select a year from the list of years. I also created a callback to display 4 graphs for each statistics using the if..else statement.
but when I ran the code using dash and I got a dropdown with only one option-'Recession Period Statistics', the dropdown to choose the years worked perfectly and finally, my output-callback.children resulted in an error.